# Convergence error of function svd() in R

Tags: r, svd, convergence

When coding in R, I find the function `svd()` may sometimes throw out the error message:

```
Error in La.svd(x, nu, nv) : error code 1 from Lapack routine 'dgesdd'.
```

After searching some  information in Google, it turns out that this error means the algorithm used in `svd()` doesn't converge. Many people also encountered the same error message and I tried many methods they used but no one works correctly, such as using parameter `LINPACK = TRUE`, rounding the matrix or even use `propack.svd()` and `trlan.svd()`.

My input data is a matrix with diagonal entries equaling to 1, and other entries are 0 or relatively small. I guess this error has something to do with the numerical precision, so I tried to round the matrix by something like `round(matrix,6)`. This will help sometimes but can't solve the problem fundamentally and I worry that this rounding will lead to some biased result.

If anyone could tell me how to solve this problem I will appreciate a lot.

Comment: Probably a problem with your input data, rather than with `svd()`. But with no description of your data, it is complicated to explore further.

Comment: The description of input data is added.

Comment: I had the same problem with svd() and large matrices when using the function in Linux,  Debian 3.10.11-1. I moved to Windows and *ironically* it worked. Not sure why though.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me for large-ish randomly generated (rnorm) matrices (e.g. run svd to get the first 6 eigenvectors for the cor of a 250 x 800 matrix filled with rnorm).  Yes, that cor matrix is rank deficient.  Do this enough times and the error pops up.
I did find that rounding to 5 digits in my case made it stop happening (at least reduces the occurrence so that it does not crop up in the large number of random trials I am doing).  Unlike OP that would not affect the quality of my results.